# Transition from Partial to Required

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design

I have a domain object `Form` and this form is being updated with data in random order.
So that makes my domain relax the required fields on the form.

Whenever user has to do an action with I the form has to be filled.

My main question: **How do you deal with transition from object having optional fields to same structure object but with all required.**

Few subquestions:

1. Does the `assertFormFilled` function makes sense?
2. Is there a way to automate assertion of all properties.
3. Am I missing some domain concept here?
4. Does `Partial<IForm>` in domain layer makes better sense than `Required<IForm>` in `doSomething`?

```
interface IForm {
  question1?: string
  question2?: boolean
  question3?: number
}

class Form implements IForm {
  question1: string | undefined
  question2: boolean | undefined
  question3: number | undefined
}

class User {
  form?: IForm
  
  doSomething = (form: Required<IForm>): void => {
    //todo use filled form
  }

  assertFormFilled = (): Required<IForm> => {
    if (this.form && this.form.question1 && !!this.form.question2 && !!this.form.question3) {
        return {
          question1: this.form.question1, 
          question2: this.form.question2, 
          question3: this.form.question3, 
          }
    }
    else {
      throw new Error('Form is not filled')
    }
  }
}


const user = new User()

user.form = { question2: false}
const form = user.assertFormFilled()
user.doSomething(form)
```

For example.

Comment: Please consider editing this so that it asks a single primary question and not [multiple equal-priority questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Comment: One might refactor to a type guard function that checks for having defined properties at particular keys, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx3Z8N).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer (after you [edit] the question to highlight a single question)

Comment: Yes, I mean `Partial<T>` and `Required<T>`

Comment: @jcalz yes after some more searching this is what I was looking for

Comment: That's quite a delayed response!  I'll write up an answer here when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't automatically use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the type of an object with an optional property to one with a required property when you check for the presence of the property.  This is a design limitation mentioned several places in GitHub issues; for example, see [microsoft/TypeScript#33205](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33205).  The issue is that such narrowing would require that the type checker synthesize new types each time a check is made (as opposed to just filtering a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) and that could negatively affect compiler performance.

So, if you want this kind of behavior, you'll have to emulate it by creating a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  For example, you could write this:

```
function hasDefinedProps<
    T extends { [P in K]?: any },
    K extends PropertyKey>(
        obj: T, ...keys: K[]
    ): obj is T & { [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[P], undefined> } {
    return keys.every(k => obj[k] !== undefined)
}
```

which lets you call something like `hasDefinedProps(obj, "foo", "bar")` and, if it returns `true`, narrows the type of `obj` to one in which the `foo` and `bar` properties are required and cannot be `undefined`.

With your example code this becomes:

```
assertFormFilled = (): Required<IForm> => {
    if (this.form && hasDefinedProps(this.form, "question1", "question2", "question3")) {
        return this.form // okay
        /* IForm & { question1: string; question2: boolean; question3: number; } */
    } else {
        throw new Error("Form is not filled");
    }
}
```

which works, because `this.form` has been narrowed from `IForm` to a type equivalent to `Required<IForm>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2UC2yDeAsAFDJnICOArhAM5jCYgCMA-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-ZrF2qUPR+OyDTgAtJIyY9uYVAxLsHajlOfK1E2UR3AGUZkKq6o5A+c4khAZzQHOix3jcdyfsOd5TsgACEcwLIh9QJMcxhAA)